# How to get MSBuild to ignore project references?

Tags: msbuild

How can I get `MSBuild` to completely ignore all the `<ProjectReference>` elements in my `.csproj`? I really want it to build just the current project, without the projects that it depends on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:MyProjectName /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

The key is the BuildProjectReferences=false parameter.

Comment: It'd be nice if you edited the optional switches out to make the flag clearer. (Platform, Config, verbosity, maxcpucount)

Comment: Also: beware: don't be tempted to add `;build` to the `t:MyProjectName` - if you do this, the entire solution will be built regardless of the BuildProjectReferences option setting.