# How to ignore dependencies with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution (ab.sln) which references two (VC) project files a.proj and b.proj. The projects depend on each other (A is a postProject ProjectDependency of B). This dependency is needed when compiling under Visual Studio.

Now I want to compile only project B from the command line and I thought msbuild would be a good choice. But I want to compile the two projects separately in different folders (for CI). After compiling A, I want to copy the required files over to the working directory for the B compile.

How can I compile one project in the solution from the command line without building the dependencies (and without having an extra file)? My current command that builds the dependency is:

```
msbuild /t:b ab.sln
```

I could of course use a separate solution file b.sln that just contains project B, but I was trying to do without the extra file.

The answer given by [jlew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7450/jlew) in [How to get MSBuild to ignore project references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597148) does not work for me, probably because I do not use *ProjectReferences*.

Answer (score 1):

If both projects used the same $(OutDir) and project B made a binary reference rather than a project reference to A in the shared $(OutDir), then it should work.

Comment: I can't find how to create binary references (are those possible for C++ as opposed to C# projects?). But I replaced my ProjectDependencies-references in the solution file with ProjectReference-references in the project files and tried the solution by jlew again. Still does not work: the referenced projects are all being build.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127377/1578962

> MSBuild myproj.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /t:Build